# Oracle Query with Explicit Values and Select

Tags: oracle, select

I am converting code between MySQL and Oracle databases. A version of this query works in MySQL but not Oracle. Some say I can't use SELECT and explicit VALUES in the same QUERY but my query does not match their examples. This fails with error `00936: missing expression`:

```
    insert into contentpacks.content_packs (CP_NAME,
                                        VERSION,
                                        DATE_DEPLOYED,
                                        TICKETNUMBER,
                                        OWNER,
                                        CP_REPLACED,
                                        ENVIRONMENT,
                                        DEPLOYED_BY,
                                        REQUESTER) 
values ('new_cp',
        '1.0.0',
        CURRENT_DATE,
        12121,
        select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters where NAME like 'J. Giacalone',
        1.0.0,
        select CENTRALNUM from contentpacks.centrals where CENTRAL_NAME like 'CDL',
        select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters where NAME like 'J. Giacalone',
        select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters WHERE NAME like 'J. Giacalone'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

try surrodunding the subselect with ()

```
insert into contentpacks.content_packs (
  CP_NAME
  ,VERSION
  ,DATE_DEPLOYED
  ,TICKETNUMBER
  ,OWNER
  ,CP_REPLACED
  ,ENVIRONMENT
  ,DEPLOYED_BY
  ,REQUESTER
) values (
  'new_cp'
  ,'1.0.0'
  ,CURRENT_DATE
  ,12121
  , (select REQNUMBER 
      from contentpacks.requesters 
        where NAME like 'J. Giacalone')
  ,'1.0.0'
  , (select CENTRALNUM 
    from contentpacks.centrals 
    where CENTRAL_NAME like 'CDL')
  , (select REQNUMBER 
    from contentpacks.requesters 
    where NAME like 'J. Giacalone')
  , (select REQNUMBER 
    from contentpacks.requesters
    WHERE NAME like 'J. Giacalone')
  )
```

Comment: I tried that originally but kept getting 00917:missing comma. insert into contentpacks.content_packs (CP_NAME,VERSION,DATE_DEPLOYED,TICKETNUMBER,OWNER,CP_REPLACED,ENVIRONMENT,DEPLOYED_BY,REQUESTER) values ('new_cp','1.0.0',CURRENT_DATE,12121,(select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters where NAME like 'J. Giacalone'),1.0.0,(select CENTRALNUM from contentpacks.centrals where CENTRAL_NAME like 'CDL'),(select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters where NAME like 'J. Giacalone'),(select REQNUMBER from contentpacks.requesters WHERE NAME like 'J. Giacalone'))